# Placing and centering div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted  to achieve the following layout.
[image: 2 divs]

basically 1 div placed inside the other.
Div1 has circle as **background image**.(size of div varies)
I want to position Div2 so as i always get the above layout

I tried using [centering a div inside another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div) ..didnt work.
Do I have to specify top and left for Div2??
I want to be able to define Div2 dimension wrt Div1.

Any help.

Edit

Using the following styles and js

```
.circle
        {
            width: 176px;
            height: 176px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: url('images/circle.png') no-repeat left top;
            display :block;
        }

.inner {
            position: absolute;
            height: 80px;
            margin: auto;
            overflow :hidden;
            white-space:normal;             
        }

Jquery :

//parent is the container c

    var $circle_div = $("<div>").attr({ id: "circle_" + id });
    $circle_div.addClass("circle");
    parent.append($circle_div);

    $circle_div.css({ "top": 100, "left": 200, position: 'absolute' });
    var $inner_div = $("<div>").attr({ id: "text_" + id });
    $inner_div.addClass("inner");
    $inner_div.html("text_circle_333333333333444444444444" + id);
    $circle_div.append($inner_div);
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatelly Kyle's answer will do nothing about centering the inner div vertically.

Liquid vertical alignment is close to impossible using CSS2.1. Given your constraints are there is a circle inside the outer div, that is as tall as the div itself, you'll need to use Javascript to calculate the absolute positioning and dimensions of the inner div that will fit in the circle.  Let's assume you give the outer's dimensions fully, and specify a given height for the inner div.

Markup

```
<div id="outer">  
 <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  backgroud-image: blah
}
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Javascript (assuming JQuery)

```
// prepare for semi-intense math
var radius = $('#outer').width()/2;
var height = $('#inner').height();
var d = Math.sqrt(radius*radius - height*height/4);

$('#inner').width(2*d)
    .css('top', (radius - height/2) + 'px')
    .css('left', (radius - d) + 'px');
```

### Edit: Explanation

What we need is to calculate `inner.left` (call it *x*), `inner.top` (call it *y*) and `inner.width` (call it *w*). This is what this problem looks like, the values in red is what we are after:

[image: Circle maths]

To note, we have an origin (0,0) for the coordinates of all points. The circle has a radius equal to `outer.width/2` (since the circle is as high and long as this div). Thus in our coordinate system, the center, of both divs and the circle, is at (*r*, *r*) (*r* = radius).

First we can deduce the y coordinate from the diagram, because we know the height *h*.

```
y = r - h/2
```

In the diagram, the point we're after lies on the circle, thus we use the equation for the circle and solve for *x*. So the equation for the circle given center at (*r*, *r*) and radius *r* (remembering high-school maths):

```
(x - r)^2 + (y - r)^2 = r^2
(x - r)^2 + (r - h/2 - r)^2 = r^2   --- replacing y
x = r ± sqrt(r^2 - 1/4*h^2)         --- solving for x
```

This x is actually two different x's, one for each point at this y coordinate and depends on whether we take the + or - square root in the answer. The one we need is the lesser of the two. The width of the inner div is given by the difference between these two x's.

```
w = r + sqrt(r^2 - 1/4*h^2) - [r - sqrt(r^2 - 1/4*h^2)]
w = 2*sqrt(r^2 - 1/4*h^2)
```

Comment: This could (potentially) also be achieved using CSS3 expressions, but I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: thx works great..but just had a doubt the height of inner div ..can it be made to the maximum possible height that can be fixed inside the square?

Comment: Ha, just was editing my answer as you posted this! good job :)

Comment: @Ezequiel Expressions is **not** a CSS3 property, but rather an propriety IE CSS extension that attempts to emulate some features of scripting.

Comment: @Amitd if you make it as high as the outer div, the width will be 0.

If you mean you want to maximise both width and height together, then set the  inner height to 2*sqrt(2)*(outer height). This will make the inner div a square.

Comment: @Ezequiel thanks a lot...maths saves the day again :)
please for the completeness of answer and my understanding ,is it possible to explain (me) the maths involved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="outer">  
     <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px /*width of image*/;
    height 100px /*height of image*/;
baackground-image: url(path-to-image/img.jpg);
}
#inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px /*whatever works*/
    width: 50%; /*or whatever width you want*/
    margin: 0px auto; */centers it horizontally*/ 
}
```

This will place the div `#inner` exactly in the center of your outer div.

**EDITED** to position the div vertically too, I missed that first time, sorry!

Hope it at least helps. :)

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work as expected ,when i tried to create the divs dynamically.

Comment: Edited my answer, but seems as Ezequiel got there before me :)

Answer (score 0):

Position div2 absolute with top and left inside relative positioned div1.

div1{position:relative}
div2{position:absolute; top:**px; left:**px}